# How to map relationship with multiple target entities

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many, one-to-one, many-to-one

I don't understand how to map bVersionId.

```java
@Data
@Table(name = "prefix_class_a")
ClassA{
    //...
    private Long bVersionId;
    //...
}
```

This tables already have ManyToOne relationship.

```java
@Data
@Table(name = "prefix_class_b")
ClassB{
    //...
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "classB")
    private Collection<ClassBVersion> versions = new ArrayList<>();
    //...
}
```

```java
@Data
@Table(name = "prefix_class_b_version")
ClassBVersion{
    //...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "prefix_class_b_id")
    private ClassB classB;
    //...
}
```

what relation should be used? And how?

Comment: Sorry, forgot: first class have relationship whith ClassB

```java
@Table(name = "prefix_class_a")
ClassA{
    //...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
    private ClassB classB;
    @Column(name = "class_b_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long classBId;

    private Long bVersionId;
    //...
}
```